# Interface implementation by client

Tags: java, interface

I have a interface and its default implementation. Both are packaged as jar and downloaded at client. however I want to provide a facility so that client can define their own implementation and basically override default implementation. Is their any standard mechanism for this ? Any special need to be followed in jar creation

Answer (score 0):

> Any special need to be followed in jar creation

No, as long as you don't [*seal*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/jar/sealman.html) the package this should be possible by default.

You will of course need a way for clients to *set* their own implementations of the interface as the one to be used by your library. But this doesn't really have to do with packaging :-)